# How to remove or delete a .txt file on SQL Server using DTS Package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, dts

What i wanted to achieve is to use DTS Package to remove a .txt file on a scheduled basis in order for another package to pick it up which in this case im using SSIS as a next step, it's just that i dont know how to delete a text file using DTS Package.

Comment: You want to use DTS (Sql server 2000) for deleting purpose and then for next steps you are using SSIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to delete a file in SSIS (no need to create any more dinosaur DTS / activex packages these days), is to use a script task. Here's the vb.net way:

Make sure you reference System.IO:

```
Imports System.IO
```

Then just run the following (replacing the filename value with the file you want to delete):

```
Public Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim filename As String = "C:\fileYouWantToDelete.txt"
        If File.Exists(filename) Then
            File.Delete(filename)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "File Killer", ex.Message, String.Empty, 0)
    End Try
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Here's a link to the DTS / vbscript way (although I highly recommend not to create dts packages, as the product is dead and someone will just have to convert your code in a few months/years): http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/187006e9-bce2-42cd-85fd-231eced17c80.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I apologize for not being clear about the SSIS Package.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the file system task, and choose the Delete file option from that task to delete your file.  No need to go to the overhead of a script task.

The file system task will allow you to copy, move, or delete a file.

Of course this is SSIS, which I agree with brian is better than using DTS to achieve your solution.

I'm not sure how deleting a file would prepare for another package to pick up the file you just deleted though.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion about the SSIS Package. but thank you again for your help.

Comment: Still not clear why you would choose a hard coded script task rather than a pre-built object that performs the same operation, but if you got it working, more power to you.